# How does JVM handle runtime exception in RMI remote method?

Tags: java, rmi, runtimeexception

I have been trying to find out how JVM handles runtime exception in RMI remote methods. I have a remote method that contains the following two methods:

```
doSomething(
 print "doSomething thread id " + Thread.currentThread.getId()
)

fail(){
 print "fail thread id " + Thread.currentThread.getId()
 throw new RunTimeException
}
```

The behavior I saw was that even if method fail() is invoked, the thread on which the runtime exception was thrown is still not terminated.  A sample output is:

```
fail thread id 16
stacktrace
 ...
doSomething thread id 16
doSomething thread id 16
```

Comment: Have you considered... you know... trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caught. The caller will get a ServerException with your RuntimeException nested in it as the cause. The executing thread doesn't die.